# ML.NET - Multi-Step Pipeline

Tags: ml.net

I've been working for a while now on teaching myself ML.NET by solving the Kaggle Titanic challenge.  I've managed to use a Binary Classification to make a fairly good guess (~77%) at the Survived/Died classification, but I'm trying to improve it now.

One of the ways I'm trying to improve it is add in a prediction for the passenger's age using a Logistic Regression.  If I make a separate pipeline it actually makes some pretty good judgements on what age a passenger is based on their details.  I'm happy with that itself.

The issue is though - how do I combine my two pipelines?  Is there a way to write a single pipeline with both steps (predict age, predict Survived, using the predicted age) or would I have to convert the data to an array after each step and treat it as entirely separate?

Something like this:

```
 raw data (has missing ages) -> filled data (ages now completed) -> survived prediction
```

I'll need to do it in such a way too, that the training is done for the "Survived" classifier with data that has had the age filled in.

Apologies if this is a bit of a basic question, but I'm relatively new to ML, and even newer to ML.NET.

I've tried running the processes separately, but for some reason the final prediction is always the exact same answer for every data item I enter into the predictor.

Thanks in advance!

Simon